# Most Efficient Memory Management C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, marshalling

I am going to be doing a project soon for my degree that requires brute force text crunching and analysis. This will obviously mean a lot of reading and writing to RAM.

What is the most efficient method of memory management in C#? Last semester I was introduced to the  [memory marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal(v=vs.100).aspx) and found this to be a very efficient method of reading and writing large amounts of data to RAM, however maybe that was just my experience. I'm hoping that someone can give me some advice or suggestions on alternatives or best practices for memory management in C#.

Thanks

Comment: An universal best practice: only do what you need to. Try making your app without using marshalling (or anything unmanaged). It works in the immense majority of the cases. If you find out through empiric eveidence you are in one of those rare cases you need unanaged memory, research it. But not before. In most cases, managed memory will be far more efficient than anything you can come up with on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient memory management system varies wildly with what you try to do in practice.

As a rule of thumb, try to stay clear of unmanaged code in C#: managed memory is more than enough for the immense majority of problems, and unless you know exactly what to do you're very unlikely to be more efficient than managed memory.

So my advice would be the following. Try a fully managed implementation, with a few good practices to prevent using too much memory:

- always dispose your disposable objects
- try mutualizing heavy assets, byte buffers for instance: instead of creating a new buffer every time you need one, use a buffer pool

If you gain empirical evidence that you need to do manual marshalling, then learn about it and use it. But not before.

Remember that a lot of people have worked on C# memory management, and that most C# developers don't need more (to the point that a lot of them don't even know how memory management works behind the scene, because they just don't need to). Managed memory in C# is pretty good, give it a shot first.